# Using require.js and mocha.js for a browser (front-end) Javascript unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js

I am trying to write a simple unit test for a simple class where I get The following error, before I even get to use my class and write some tests!:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setup' of undefined
```

Running this line:

```
require(['mocha'], function(mocha){
    mocha.setup('bdd');
});
```

My basic html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="mocha"></div>
      <script data-main="SpecRunner" src="./require.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

SpecRunner.js:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "./",
  paths: {
    mocha: 'node_modules/mocha/mocha'
  }
});

require(['mocha'], function(mocha){
    mocha.setup('bdd');
    //mocha.run();
});
```

I installed mocha using npm (and there is mocha.js inside node_modules/mocha/).

What is wrong with my setup?